# How do I find the file name of a Rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, how do I find the file name of the partial that would be rendered by `render 'foo'`?

Comment: Depends where it is being called from. Most likely located: /app/views/foos/show.html.erb (or .haml, .slim).

Comment: I think @Zenph means `/app/views/{current_controller's_folder}/_foo.html.erb`. @Zenph's answer does apply if the call to `render` is in your controller action though.

Comment: It appears the above is both correct and wrong. Even in controller (not application_controller), the render is still relative to the controllers' views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, you get two different results if you call `render` from within a controller, and `render` from within tags in a view.

In a controller `bar` calling `render 'foo'` would result in rendering the file `<project>/app/views/bar/foo.html.erb`.

In a *view* e.g. `<project>/app/views/bar/show.html.erb` calling `<% render 'foo' %>` would result in including the partial `<project>/app/views/bar/_foo.html.erb` into the `show.html.erb` view. The partial is taken from the same directory as the view.

And to make things a little more complex, if you put folder names into the render e.g. `render 'shared/foo'` this is relative to `<project>/app/views`.

So:

```
Controller: render 'foo'              = <project>/app/views/<controller name>/foo.html.erb
            render 'shared/foo'       = <project>/app/views/shared/foo.html.erb
View:       <% render 'foo' %>        = _foo.html.erb in directory of view
            <% render 'shared/foo' %> = <project>/app/views/shared/_foo.html.erb
```

P.S. if you specify a different `:format` in your `render` command, then the `html.erb` needs to change accordingly (e.g. `js.erb`, `js.coffee.erb`, etc etc).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials